# Is this problem doable with the information given?

Tags: stoichiometry, elemental-analysis

Can I solve this problem without knowing any starting amounts?

An element $\ce{X}$ forms iodide ($\ce{XI3}$) and chloride ($\ce{XCl3}$). The iodide is quantitatively converted to the chloride when it is heated in a stream of chlorine:

$$\ce{2 XI3 + 3Cl2 -> 2XCl3 + 3I2}$$

Calculate the atomic mass of $\ce{X}$. Identify element $\ce{X}$.

Comment: Hi and welcome to chemistry.stackexchange.com. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. I improved the formatting of your post using MathJax. More information on how to do so yourself can be found in the [help] and [this meta post](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/444/7475).

Comment: Also, the problem is not solveable without the masses of reactant and product.